# one div over another

Tags: css, html

ive been making pages using tables forever. recently ive been trying to switch to divs since everyone seems to have done that, and its been a pain. anyway i was thinking if anyone could be nice enough to help me figure this one out. i have attached a picture that will explain the problem because after all a picture's worth a thousand words. thanks in advance.

[image removed]

Comment: ads from your link drive to pron sites, avoid using "host image to earn sites"

Comment: You shouldn't think like tables vs. divs. It is using 2D slices vs. potentially overlapping layers. :) Also I have no idea whatsoever what do you mean by "need the left and right Xs look like the navigation bar and with a width that stretches with page". Maybe punctuation would actually help in this case?
  
Would this example help you? http://peterned.home.xs4all.nl/examples/csslayout1.html

Comment: Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/7644427/edit) and upload the image to our image host, imgur, using the [provided toolbar icon](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post)

Answer (score 2):

do you mean something like this?

**html:**

```
<div id="content"><br/></div>
<div id="navigation"><div><br/></div></div>
```

**css:**

```
html,body{
    height:100%;
    margin:0;  
    padding:0;
}
#content{
    width:800px;
    border:1px solid red;
    min-height:100%;
    margin:0 auto;
    position:relative;
}
#navigation{
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    width:100%;
    height:100px;
    background:gray;
}
#navigation div{
    width:800px;
    height:100%;
    background:lightgray;
    position:relative;
    margin:0 auto; 
}
```

**demo:**
http://jsfiddle.net/Z8UDf/

Answer (score 1):

To center a div use CSS margins:

```
<div style="width: 800px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

Inside that div you can then place your navigation bar which will fill up the space available to it.

With regards to the spaces either side of the main content you have two options.

- You can set a `background-image` on the body at `top repeat-x` so that it appears that you have a horizontal bar right the way across your page.
- You can split the navigation from the main body, have both centered using the method above. Wrap the top 'navigation' div with another div that will be 100% width. You can then style that div as you wish. This has the advantage that you can move it without updating your background images.

Answer (score 0):

use css style

```
<div style="position:absolute;left:100px;top:150px;" > MyDiv1 </div>
<div style="position:absolute;left:130px;top:150px;" > MyDiv2 </div>
```

Comment: im sorry but i dont see how this is going to work. the main container's supposed to be in the middle of the page (regardless of the resolution). i can't make the position absolute.